Git workflow using VM no internet
I have a VM with windows 10 installed where I do all my work, git is also installed. But I don't have internet access so I can't push directly from the VM.
Here is how I push things to GitHub.

The repo is cloned into the shared folder on the host.
Local repo is cloned from the shared folder in VM to Desktop. All the work is done here.
Git remote has been configured so if I type git remote -v in shared folder on VM I can see the Desktop repo as my local.
A local branch is created on the desktop VM called test_local where all changes is done.
All changes are commited local on the test_local branch
To fetch the local changes I have a branch in the shared folder with the same name excluding the _local so in this example test.
From the test branch in shared folders I type git pull local test_local to pull all my changes.
From the shared folder on the host the code is then pushed to GitHub using git push origin master.

Problems.
When I need to do changes to the same commit using git commit --amend on the test_local branch and trying to git pull them not using git pull --rebase local test_local to avoid duplicated commits I almost always gets merge conflicts on all changes. When using rebase they should be merge together on the same commit? When solving the merge conflicts on shared folder on VM a new commit is created and I can't push the code because of duplicated commits.
Why is this, and can I improve my workflow using git and VM with no internet access in some way?

“with no internet access”—what’s the use of the GitHub remote in this case? What’s the relevance to the workflow?
